# regexp: match character group or end of line

Tags: python, regex

How do you match `^` (begin of line) and `$` (end of line) in a `[]` (character group)?

---

simple example

haystack string: `zazty`

rules:

1. match any "z" or "y"
2. if preceded by

   1. an "a", "b"; or
   2. at the beginning of the line.

pass:
match the first two "z"

a regexp that would work is:
`(?:^|[aAbB])([zZyY])`

But I keep thinking  it would be much cleaner with something like that meant beginning/end of line inside the character group
`[^aAbB]([zZyY])`
 (in that example assumes the `^` means beginning of line, and not what it really is there, a negative for the character group)

---

note: using python. but knowing that on bash and vim would be good too.

Update: read again the [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) it says for set of chars, everything lose it's special meaning, except the character classes (e.g. `\w`)

down on the list of character classes, there's `\A` for beginning of line, but this does not work `[\AaAbB]([zZyY])`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't match a `^` or `$` within a `[]` because the only characters with special meaning inside a character class are `^` (as in "everything but") and `-` (as in "range") (and the character classes). `\A` and `\Z` just don't count as character classes.

This is for all (standard) flavours of regex, so you're stuck with `(^|[stuff])` and `($|[stuff])` (which aren't all that bad, really).

Comment: well, it IS bad because, in python, i'm now stuck with `findall()`. as `search()` will also return the characters matched with `(?:...)`. Not the end of the world, I know...

Comment: Couldn't you use capturing brackets around the bit you want and use `match.group(1)`? You already have the capturing brackets there. `m.start(1)`, `m.end(1)`, etc.

Comment: with negative lookbehind you can actually do that, look at my answer below

Comment: @gcb, try look behinds. Behavior of `search` may differ.

Comment: don't know why, but for `search('(?:a)(z)')`, i get "az". i'm using `findall('(?:a)(z)')` for now wich return proper matching groups just fine (in this case just "z"), even though i only need the first match

Comment: Do `m=re.search('(?:a)(z)','zazty'); print m.group(1)`. That will extract just the 'z'. Or, lookarounds are 0-width as the other commenters have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the character 'a' to the beginning of the string. Then use `[aAbB]([zZyY])`.

Comment: that's actually pretty clever

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?<![^abAB])([yzYZ])
```

Comment: I wonder whether positive or negative look behinds are more efficient in terms of this task.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying escape character `\`? (`[\^\$]`)

UPDATE:
If you want to find all Zs and As preceded by "a" than you can use positive lookbehind. Probably there is no way to specify wild cards in character groups (because wild cards are characters too). (It there is I would be pleased to know about it).

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<=(?:^|[aA]))([zZyY])");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher("zazty");

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("matcher.group(0) = " + matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println("matcher.start() = " + matcher.start());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
matcher.group(0) = z
matcher.start() = 0
matcher.group(0) = z
matcher.start() = 2
```

Comment: Nah, then it just means a literal `^` -- still not "beginning of line".

Comment: special chars (e.g. ^+!*?...) lose their meaning. ^ becomes "not" if it's the first char.

Comment: isn't the look-behind group extraneous? i mean, you are passing a non-matching group to the look-behind group

Comment: you still have a non-capturing group and the *or* condition this way

Comment: @gcb, yes it is. But you might want to leave it because it explicitly shows that there is no match.